# How to make an android layout have a shadow from elevation while transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, transparent, shadow

[image]

I created an app with android studio and in this app I have a transparent layout, this layout has elevation and in the preview it has a shadow. For some reason I cannot seem to make the app on my phone look the same.

tl;dr: the image shows exactly what I want and is how it looks in Android Studio but it does not look the same on the app on my phone.

Comment: can you show us the code how to have done shadow plus the min android version supported by your app

Comment: all I did was add an elevation of 25dp to the layout. Min is 22

Comment: we need to see the code to actually help

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="#1affffff">